# Java program to connect to aws s3 using Hadoop-aws and check if the bucket is present or not

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I have written a code to connect to aws s3 storage using hadoop configuration and filesystem but it doesnot providing the correct answer.

Even if we donot provide accesskey and secretkey and wrong bucket name it returns true..

```
public class AwsConfig3 {
    static String path="s3a://Your_bucketname";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
         Configuration config=new Configuration();
         config.set("fs.s3a.access.key", "Your_AccessKey");
         config.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "Your_SecretKey");
         config.set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem");
         
         FileSystem fs=FileSystem.get(new URI(path),config);
         Path path1=new Path(fs.getUri());
         if (fs.exists(path1)) {
            System.out.println("path exist");
        }
         else
         {
             System.out.println("path not exist");
         }
         
         
    }

}
```

It returns "path exist" even if we put the wrong bucket name.

Answer (score 0):

The S3A connector always returns true for stat("/"); performance optimisation as a lot of code calls it. A listStatus("/") would do a list.

you can change `fs.s3a.bucket.probe` from its default of 0 to either "1" or "2" for an early check. its been disabled for a while as all it did was slow construction down. But if you set it, that FileSystem.get would fail

Finally, cut the `config.set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem");`. That configuration parameter is set by default in the hadoop jars. *There is no need for this, it exists only as stack overflow superstition*